# How can I get "Drawing Like" effect?

Tags: photo-editing

What effect is used in this image?

[image: Sample image]

[Bigger photo](http://500px.com/photo/12738487).

Comment: Do you want to achieve that affect in the photo or turn that photo into a "drawing"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knew this style looked familiar. Took me whole day to remember what plugin it was.

( Not 100% sure the same plugin was used in your example image, but it's at least very similar )

[Fractalius filter plugin](http://www.redfieldplugins.com/filterFractalius.htm)

> Fractalius plugin creates unusual, eccentric artworks in a single step. The effects are based on extraction of so-called hidden fractal texture of an image. You can also simulate various types of exotic lightings and high realistic pencil sketches.

Example of an image made with Fractalius:

[image]

Tutorial for using fractalius:

http://techfleece.com/2011/01/30/fractalius-tutorial/ - Had a second glance of this tutorial and you'd probably find better ones with google.

Comment: Good find. Unfortunately it's a Windows-only plug in.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm using Lightroom 4 and when I try to edit a .CR2 (Canon RAW) to edit the file in Photoshop, the Redfield menu is grayed out, does Redfield work just with JPEGs?

Comment: @AkramMellice I think it might be grey because of your color mode. It only likes RGB color mode.

Answer (score 4):

Can also look into this very popular plugin package called [Topaz Glow](https://www.topazlabs.com/glow) available from their website as a trial or to buy.

Screenshot from their website, and yes it does really work this well. I haven't bought it yet but have done the trial and am considering it

[image]

Comment: Seems like a more viable option, given that Fractalius plugin is older than time itself. Pretty expensive though...