# How can I achieve this glowing effect on my images?

Tags: photoshop-effects, lighting-effects

[image: Glowing Image]

[image: Glowing Image 2]

I've looked around for tutorials but I'm not quite sure how it's achieved. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related discussion: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/how-can-i-get-drawing-like-effect?lq=1